# OpenGL Skybox rendering wrong

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to implement a skybox and then use the cube map for the skybox to make a reflective sphere in my scene using some code I found editing to fit my project. The skybox shows but the image is almost corrupted looking, there is a basic outline of the mountains but no colour as you can see in the image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPFZx.jpg
I've been trying to make sure active texture and my shaders are correct but I just can't figure it out.

Vertex and fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
out vec3 TexCoords;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;


void main()
{
   vec4 pos = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
   gl_Position = pos.xyww;
   TexCoords = position;
}  
#version 330 core
in vec3 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;

uniform samplerCube skybox;

void main()
{    
    color = texture(skybox, TexCoords);
}
```

Load cubemap

```
GLuint loadCubemap(std::vector<const GLchar*> faces)
{
    GLuint textureID;
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);

    int width, height, numComponents;
    unsigned char* image;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);
    for (GLuint i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
    {
        image = stbi_load(faces[i], &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        stbi_image_free(image);
    }
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, 0);

    return textureID;
}
```

Drawing skybox

```
            glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  
            skyShader.Bind();
            skyShader.Update(transform, camera);
            view = glm::mat4(glm::mat3(camera.GetViewProjection()));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyShader.getProg(), "view"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
            glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(skyShader.getProg(), "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

            glBindVertexArray(skyboxVAO);
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(skyShader.getProg(), "skybox"), 0);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, skyboxTexture);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
            glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
```

Let me know if any other parts would be useful to see

Comment: I'm a beginner with OpenGL myself, so I may very likely be wrong, but this looks like a mismatch of how the texture was read in, and how OpenGL is interpreting it. I never used stb, but it looks like you may be reading in the texture with 4 components per pixel, but then fed it to OpenGL as 3 components per pixel, resulting in every 3rd component being interpreted as red instead of alpha, or something along those lines.

Comment: You were exactly right! I just changed it to image = stbi_load(faces[i], &width, &height, &numComponents, 3); and it fixed it, thank you so much

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Comment: I'm having more issues now trying to use the same cube map for reflections, probably missing something small again because I'm so new to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34970832/opengl-reflection-shader-showing-only-grey

Comment: sorry, wish I made it that far with graphics. I'm doing skyboxes much later. Right now I'm just around basic textures, and I'm trying to figure out lighting models and materials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The texture was read in, and fed to OpenGL with inconsistent number of components per pixel

`image = stbi_load(faces[i], &width, &height, &numComponents, 4);` read in the image with 4 components

But when you fed it to OpenGL, `glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);` you fed it as a texture with 3 components per pixel, causing every 4 bytes to be interpreted as red when it should've been something else